# CUDA float matrix multiplication gives the wrong answer

Tags: floating-point, cuda, gpu, matrix-multiplication

I  recently started  to program with CUDA. I wrote this code in which two matrices are initialized.
Then these matrices are multiplied by each other by passing them in the `GPU_setup_MaMul` function. But if I do this, the answer is wrong.

I checked the code multiple times, but I can't find the mistake. I tried to print out the values from the matrix multiplication  and sometimes it seems that the kernel accesses the wrong data, and if it accesses the right data, the answer to the multiplication is sometimes 0 (by two non-0 floats).

Furthermore, I also wrote the code for integer matrix multiplication; with integers, I had no problems.

Does anyone know what the problem is?

```
#include <iostream>
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"

__global__ void matrixMulGPU(float* a, float* b, float* c, int M_, int N_, int K_)
{
    //calcukeate row and colum
    int row = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
    int col = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;

    if ((row < M_ && col < K_))
    {
        int temp = 0;


        for (int i = 0; i < N_; i++) {
            
            temp += a[row * N_ + i] * b[i * K_ + col];
            printf("Thread [%f, %f]: temp = %f\n", a[row * N_ + i], b[i * K_ + col], temp);
        }
        c[row * K_ + col] = temp;

    }
}

void GPU_setup_MaMul(float* h_a, float* h_b, float* h_c, int M, int N, int K) {
    float* d_a, * d_b, * d_c;
    cudaMalloc(&d_a, M * N * sizeof(float));
    cudaMalloc(&d_b, N * K * sizeof(float));
    cudaMalloc(&d_c, M * K * sizeof(float));

    cudaMemcpy(d_a, h_a, N * M * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(d_b, h_b, N * K * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    dim3 threadsPerBlock(16, 16);
    dim3 numBlocks((M + 16 - 1) /16, (K + 16 - 1) / 16);
    matrixMulGPU << <numBlocks, threadsPerBlock >> > (d_a, d_b, d_c, M, N, K);
    
    cudaMemcpy(h_c, d_c, M * K * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    cudaFree(d_a);
    cudaFree(d_b);
    cudaFree(d_c);
}

void init_Scale(float x,float y,float z,float w,float* zu_verschieben,int lenght, int height) {

    zu_verschieben[0] = x;
    zu_verschieben[1 * lenght + 1] = y;
    zu_verschieben[2 * lenght + 2] = z;
    zu_verschieben[3 * lenght + 3] = w;


    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            std::cout << " " << zu_verschieben[i * 4 + j];
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
    }


}

#define LENGHT 50
#define HEIGHT 3
#define COL_TRI 4
#define ROW_TRI 50
int main()
{
    size_t bytes_2 = (COL_TRI)*ROW_TRI * sizeof(float);
    
    float * Scale, * Scale2, * answer;
    Scale = (float*)calloc(COL_TRI, COL_TRI * sizeof(float));
    Scale2 = (float*)calloc(COL_TRI, COL_TRI * sizeof(float));
    answer = (float*)calloc(COL_TRI, COL_TRI * sizeof(float));

    init_Scale(3.0f, 3.0f, 2.0f, 2.0f, Scale2, COL_TRI, COL_TRI);
    init_Scale(3.0f, 3.0f, 2.0f, 2.0f, Scale, COL_TRI, COL_TRI);
    GPU_setup_MaMul(Scale, Scale2, answer, COL_TRI, COL_TRI, ROW_TRI);


    
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            std::cout << " " << answer[i * 4 + j];
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
    }



    free(triMa);
    triMa = NULL;

    free(Scale);
    Scale = NULL;
    

    return 0;
}
 

When I multiply the matrix,
[[3,0,0,0]
[0,3,0,0]
[0,0,2,0]
[0,0,0,2]]
with itself, the answer that I get is
[[9,0,0,0]
[0,9,0,0]
[0,0,6,0]
[0,0,0,6]]
but it should be 
[[9,0,0,0]
[0,9,0,0]
[0,0,4,0]
[0,0,0,4]]
Also, when I multiply the matrix:
[[2,0,0,0]
[0,3,0,0]
[0,0,2,0]
[0,0,0,2]] 
with itself, I get:

[[4,0,0,0]
[0,6,0,0]
[0,0,4,0]
[0,0,0,4]]
instead of
[[4,0,0,0]
[0,9,0,0]
[0,0,4,0]
[0,0,0,4]]
```

Comment: Passing `temp` (has type `int`) to `%f` format specifier of `printf` (expects `double`) invokes *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Why are you using `ROW_TRI` (`50`) for multiplication of 4x4 matrices?

Comment: Please check the "How to get useful answers to your CUDA questions" section of the [cuda tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/cuda/info) for debugging steps that might help you find the problem on yourself like checking return values from CUDA Runtime API functions and running the application through sanitizers.